# How to calculate resistors of this VCCS

Tags: power-supply

[image]

R1(e.g. 1KΩ) How to get the value of R2 R3 R4...R6?
If someone have the answer, Thanks!

Here is the context of the diagram.

[image]

Comment: Is this a homework?  If not, please give us more context.  What is the nature and goal of the experiment?  Where does the diagram come from?

Comment: There definitely isnt enough information in this diagram to determine exact values of anything.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Thanks for the comments! more information about the diagram had been added.

Comment: @efox29 Thanks for the comments! more information about the diagram had been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AI is a difference amplifier, and it says that in order to have a high desired output impedance, you should be using matched resistors. So \$R_{\text{a}}\$, \$R_{\text{b}}\$, and \$R_{\text{c}}\$ and \$R_{\text{d}}\$ are all the same.

The current through \$R_1\$ will be \$-V_{\text{in}}/R_1\$, so for whatever your desired current is, adjust \$R_1\$ appropriately.

Let's look at a typical difference amplifier

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc73c1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$ V_{\text{out}} = \frac {R_3}{R_1}(S_a - S_b) $$ when \$R_1 = R_2\$ and \$R_3 = R_4\$. In this case, since all the resistors are the same, \$V_{\text{out}}\$ is actually just the difference with unity gain.

So what is the voltage for \$S_a\$? Well, it's the same voltage as Node A.

So the output of AI is \$V_{\text{out}} = V_{\text{a}} - V_{\text{in}}\$

The current through \$R_1\$  is $$ I_{R_1} = \frac {V_{\text{out}} - V_{\text{a}}}{R_1} $$ 
So the current is really $$I_{R_1} = \frac {-V_{\text{in}}}{R_1} $$

The text says that node B is meant to be the same magnitude but just opposite polarity as node A, so \$R_2\$ and \$R_3\$ must be equal to each other, since the gain of a inverting op amp configuration is \$\frac{-R_3}{R_2}\$, and we want a gain of -1.

\$R_6\$ is your load, and \$R_4\$ and \$R_5\$ are your wire/lead resistance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer which is very useful and help me to understand the diagram. Really thanks!